# How can I make the line under the links the same size as the text using CSS?

Tags: html, css, next.js

```
    <div className={styles.container}>
  <ul className={styles.links}>
    <li className={styles.link}>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li className={styles.link}>
      <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li className={styles.link}>
      <a href="/skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li className={styles.link}>
      <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

    .link a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.link a:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  color: #f8b513;
}

.link a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%; 
  bottom: -3px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}

.link a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1); 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the underline the same size as the text with the effect applied when hover effect is applied on the links.

[image]

[image]

As seen in the images, the length of the line formed under all of them is 100%. However, I want the line under it to be as long as the word Portfolio, and I want the line under it to be as long as the word home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to wrap the text in a `span` and then use the pseudo-element on that. `.link a span::after`

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {

  flex:1;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border:1px solid red;
  text-align:center;

}

span {
  position: relative;;
}

span:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left:0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  transition: width .33s ease;
}

a:hover span:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/"><span>Lorem.</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/"><span>Lorem, ipsum.</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/"><span>Item 3</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/"><span>Item 4</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/"><span>Item 5</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

It will be solved your problem.
width: min-content;

```
a:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
      width: min-content;
    }
```